# How to print the wpf Mainwindow which is scrollable?

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

In my WPF application i have a listbox in which there are many items and my window has scrolling functionality so that i need the complete page to be print i tried the following code it is printing only the visible window portion only but not till the end of the window how to achieve this looking for the genuine help.

```
private void Canvas_Print_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
                PrintDialog printdlg = new PrintDialog();
                MainWindow win = new MainWindow();
                win.Tag = this;
                if (printdlg.ShowDialog() == true)
                {
                    printdlg.PrintVisual(this, "Myapplication Name");
                }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Ok I am taking this code from this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/be2edad6-f075-4295-ab22-3657eba78043/how-to-print-the-entire-of-a-wpf-window-that-scrolls?forum=wpf)

```
PrintDialog dlg = new PrintDialog();
this.Width = 350;
panel.ScrollToTop();
if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    dlg.PrintVisual(panel.Content as Visual, "Print Button");
}
```

You can visit this [link](http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?id=66#.U48xd9yD-GQ) for your answer too... This resizes your windows to fit the content. If you do not want that you can visit this [link](http://www.slickthought.net/post/2009/05/26/Visual-Tree-Printing-in-WPF-Applications.aspx).

Comment: Hi Syed, Thanks for the reply but what you have mentioned in the above links are about only printing the specific part only i want my complete window to be print i have a scroll bar for my entire window if i'm doing with the above code then it is printing the specific part which is visible only and including the scroll bar, what i want is i need to print the entire window and the scroll bar should not be printed.

Comment: Did you visit the link and read all the posts? They are for printing the whole window, and they describe a situation similar to yours...